# NLog: How to use function (plain code) instead of layout string?

Tags: c#, nlog

Specifying message format via declarative layout string is a easy way but only in simple cases.

When I see conditions or nested layouts I want to use plain code to format my message.

How can I format my messages via plain code?

Comment: With plain code, do you mean, set the Layout value in C#?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: OK added the C# tag, as stackoverflow works with more languages ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create your own custom Layout-class:

```
class CustomLayout : Layout
{
    protected string GetFormattedMessage(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
         // Legacy-style
         return "King of the world";
    }

    protected override void RenderFormattedMessage(LogEventInfo logEvent, StringBuilder target)
    {
         // New style supports reusable StringBuilder (reduces allocation)
         target.Append(GetFormattedMessage(logEvent));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I just realized that Layout is not string))

Answer (score 2):

You can always register your own custom layout renderer that generates whatever wonderful pattern you like:

```
LayoutRenderer.Register("king", (logEvent) => "King of the World");
```

Just make sure to register the layout before loading the NLog-config (or creating any NLog-Logger objects, including static Logger-objects).

Then you can use your custom-layoutrenderer in the Layout like normal (Ex. `${king}`)

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

See also: https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/T_NLog_LogEventInfo.htm (Available `logevent`-properties)

Comment: Sorry to have offended you. Please create a PullRequest for the NLog-project showing how to implement proper message-formatting.

Comment: Why sorry?! Thank you for your answer. I think it works. But it looks like a crutch.